# Simulate Android's Webview on PC's Firefox?

Tags: android, firefox, webview, android-webview

As part of my software development job (for Android), I need to inspect the content of numerous HTML pages when viewed via Android's WebView.

So far, I have been able to accomplish that by dumping the HTML content to a file in `/data/data/<package-name>/files/`, then using `adb pull` to copy it to the PC for easier and more comfortable inspection (larger screen and a keyboard).

I would like, however, to accelerate the process by dumping that content to a file directly from my Firefox browser on my PC. I have heard of so called "[User Agent Switchers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)" add-ons that can fool the remote site to be thinking it communicates with a different type of browser, but can this really work when not only an agent string need to be emulated but also the **screen size**?

Your learned advice and tips would very much appreciated.

Comment: Screen size and user agent string are not the only factors in a complete emulation: Firefox does not natively support the mime-type `application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml` which is one of the possible mime-types for XHTML Mobile Profile. So you may want to check the [XHTML Mobile Profile](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xhtml-mobile-profile/?src=api) add-on as well.

Comment: Can't you just resize your browser to emulate screen size?

Comment: @Nathan Fig Good idea. Do you know of any way to make Firefox switch from one **pre-set** screen size to another? That would make the process even less tedious. +1.

Comment: @ef2011 Thanks. I'll check that. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use the user agent switcher.

2) Get the [mobile profile addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xhtml-mobile-profile/?src=api).

3) Resize the window to emulate screen size changes. A quick Google search finds an addon that can handle preset window resizing: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/window-resizer/ (If this won't do, look around the addon site- there are multiple that can do this).