# Strange blue colour on Popup JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am facing strange issue with JQuery mobile pop up, when I am appending popup to the body strange blue colour appearing on POP up. Can anyone help me on this? which CSS can avoid this issue?

> This issue only on Android 4.2 or below devices

[image: Strange blue color]

Comment: If you open it in a browser on your PC (with Android user agent), do you get the same result?

Comment: No in browser it's working fine, no issue with it

Comment: Even when you try it with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900755/simulate-androids-webview-on-pcs-firefox ? The reason I ask is, when you can simulate it in a browser on your pc, you can have a look with the element inspector what is causing the problem.

Comment: I have done inspection with Google mobile simulator, there all seems fine. I didn't find this kind of blue color on popup. in IOS and other Android 4.4 devices it's working fine. Only problem with 4.2 or below devices.